# How to grab all headers from a website using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to grab all the headers from a simple website. My attempt:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

url = "http://nypost.com/business"
page = requests.get(url)
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
soup.find_all('h')
```

`soup.find_all('h')` returns `[]`, but if I do something like `soup.h1` or `soup.h2`, it returns that respective data. Am I just calling the method incorrectly?

Comment: shouldn't you do `soup.find_all('h1')` and `soup.find_all('h2')`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Filter by regular expression:

```
soup.find_all(re.compile('^h[1-6]$'))
```

This regex finds all tags that start with `h`, have a digit after the `h`, and then end after the digit.

Comment: I'm finally understanding this library more... is there a way of knowing how many digits there are?

Comment: My regexp allows only one, from 1 to 6. HTML only has headers from `H1` to `H6`. Why do you expect more? Have you ever seen a page with `H16`?!

Comment: I am a complete newbie to this, just found out HTML has maximum 6. Thank you for your help~

Answer (score 3):

If you do not wish to use regex then you might wanna do something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://nypost.com/business"

page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")
for headlines in page.find_all("h3"):
    print(headlines.text.strip())
```

Results:

```
The epitome of chic fashion is the latest victim of retail's collapse
Rent-a-Center shares soar after rejecting takeover bid
NFL ad revenue may go limp with loss of erectile-dysfunction ads
'Pharma Bro' talked about sex with men to get my money, investor says

And So On------
```

Answer (score 3):

when using the method find or find_all you can pass a string or a list of tags

```
soup.find_all([f'h{i}' for i in range(1,7) ])
```

or

```
soup.find_all(['h{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,7)])
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to do `soup.find_all('h1')`

you could do something like:

```
for a in ["h1","h2"]:
  soup.find_all(a)
```

Comment: This seems like the closest to what I was looking for. I noticed that there was h1, h2, h3, h4 for this site (by typing in manually). How would I know, in other cases, the number of "h's" that exist?

Comment: well, technically there could be N number of `h` tags, if you want to automate it completely, then you could brute force through all the `h` tags in a loop although that might be very very inefficient. I am not sure of a better way to do this.